# Suppress Exception and Error in Shiny Server data.table

Tags: r, shiny-server

I am grouping data on a column and trying to use fitdistplus package to fit my data for every group. In some groups, I am getting exception:

> the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
>                   with the error code 52

I want to ignore this and proceed with other groups' fitting. I tried `tryCatch` but it isn't suppressing the error. Could someone help me in this?

Thanks

```
fits <- df[!is.na(x)
       , {
         tryCatch({
           if(length(x) > 1){
             fit <- fitdist(c(x), distr="norm",method = "mle",lower=lower,upper=upper);
             if(distribution_type == "exp" | distribution_type=="pois"){
               tempList<- list(est1 = fit$estimate[[1]],est3=.N);
               names(tempList)<- c(names(fit$estimate[1]),"count");
               tempList
             }
             else{
               tempList<- list(est1 = fit$estimate[[1]], est2 = fit$estimate[[2]],est3=.N)
               #print(names(fit$estimate[[1]]);
               names(tempList)<- c(names(fit$estimate[1]),names(fit$estimate[2]),"count");
               tempList
             }
           }
         },error = function(e){message(e)}) 
       }
       , by = group_by_column]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the error. I am printing `message(e)` in the exception which is send back to the caller.

`error=function(e){}` worked.